# how to parse rss xml?

Tags: iphone

i am using below url for rss parsing.
http://news.baidu.com/n?cmd=4&class=finannews&tn=rss

But it gives error code 31.Is it possible parsing this type of rss.
If yes then plese give me idea about that.

I am using below code.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];      
        [xmlParser setClassName:className withRootName:rootName];
        [xmlParser setDelegate:xmlParser];
        [xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [xmlParser parse];
        [m_delegate setData:xmlParser.message items:xmlParser.items];
        //[xmlParser release];
        [pool release];
```

Comment: did you look what error code 31 means? Since that site is not using unicode (I assume) might that be part of the reason?

Answer (score 1):

since the feed is in Chinese the  characters recognized are in some type of codes.

Try decoding those codes and feed will be parsed correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

Use [google-data-api](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-objectivec-client-1.9.1.zip&can=2&q=) for parsing of feeds like this. it will give you the relevant information in the form categorised data-structure. For your help I am posting some of the code that might give you some hint.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *feedURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];
    GDataFeedBase *feedBase = [[GDataFeedBase alloc] initWithData:data];
    NSArray *linksArr = [feedBase links];
    if(feedArray == nil){
        [self setFeedArray:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }
    [feedArray addObjectsFromArray:[feedBase entries]];
    [feedBase release];
    [feedURL release];
    [pool release];
```

Now in the feed array you will have the relevant information.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup